# gsutil rsync exits after starting synchronization

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rsync, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I'm trying to sync folders from Google compute engine instance to cloud storage, but it just exits without any pointers whatsoever. It says *Starting synchronization* and then goes back to the prompt.

```
gsutil -m rsync -r public/ gs://mybucket/public
Building synchronization state...
Starting synchronization
```

My gsutil version

```
gsutil version -l
gsutil version: 4.6
checksum: 397d8391fddbf1c48cc31f9c2911be68 (!= 70858e3360112a908c76273e6c947098)
boto version: 2.30.0
python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) [GCC 4.8.2]
OS: Linux 3.16.0-62-generic
multiprocessing available: True
using cloud sdk: True
config path: /etc/boto.cfg
gsutil path: /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil
compiled crcmod: False
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
```

I also tried updating gsutil and gcloud components respectively, but that doesn't work either

```
gcloud components update
You cannot perform this action because the component manager has been 
disabled for this installation.  If you would like get the latest 
version of the Google Cloud SDK, please see our main download page at:

  https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The component manager is disabled for this installation
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

Comment: 4.6 is a fairly old version of gsutil and a lot of reliability fixes have been added since then.  You may want to install Cloud SDK from the main download page (or see if running components update as root works)

Answer (score 5):

When gsutil rsync outputs nothing more than "Starting synchronization" (with no "Copying" output), that means it found nothing needing synchronization between the source and destination you specified.

Comment: So if i want to delete the bucket content and upload the new files and dirs, how should I do it?

Comment: To delete all objects in a bucket you can run a command like gsutil -m rm gs://my-bucket/**

Comment: Note that "it found nothing" could also indicate that the user executing gsutil does not have the necessary filesystem permissions (if the source is on the local filesystem, for example).